# "Differ to", "differ with" or "differ from"

Tags: idioms, word-choice, phrasal-verbs

In what ways are *differ to*, *differ with* and *differ from* different?

Providing examples would be really appreciated.

Comment: I guess the `versus` tag would be really good after a while it would consist lots of questions like this which I believe are really informative and useful.

Comment: Note that there is no idiom that uses "differ to", as indicated by Mepher's answer.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ I'm fairly sure I've heard Britons say "*X* is different **to** *Y*"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/differ) gives a definition of "differ" together with good examples:

> 1. to be different from something else
>
>    **differ in:** *The two animals come from the same family but differ in body shape and breeding habits.*
>
>    **differ from:** *English differs from Spanish in that it is not pronounced as it is written.*
>
>    **differ widely/significantly/greatly (=be very different):** *Laws on
>      pollution differ widely from one country to another.*
>
>    **differ from something to something:** *The techniques used differ from company to company.*
> 2. to disagree with someone about a subject
>
>    **differ on/over:** *Experts differ on the causes of the disease.*
>
>    **opinions/views differ:** *Opinions differ as to the likely winner of the tournament.*
>
>    **differ with:** *Baker also differed with members of Congress over this issue.*
>
>    **beg to differ (=disagree):** *I beg to differ with you a bit there.*

Answer (score 2):

[Mehper's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1057/127) is comprehensive, but if you want to settle on one I would recommend "differ from". The thing to remember is that we are talking about the opposite of being similar *to* something. Since "to" and "from" are opposites, it's logical that the opposite of "(be) similar *to*" is "differ(ent) *from*".

I know that English isn't always logical but in this case it conforms nicely. As an aside, a real pet hate of mine is "different than" - it makes me wince every time I see or hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the word you're looking for is *defer*, which means "to put-off/delay", or when used in the idiom "defer to" with an object, "to yield (to) or comply (with) the wishes or judgments of another: I defer to your superior knowledge."

See: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/defer

Comment: What makes you think that they were looking for *defer*?

Comment: *Differ* and *defer* can be confused easily because they sound similar. I'm here for this exact reason! So this was a very helpful answer to me. Although, I admit this does not answer the question above.