# Prepositions used with "different"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, comparisons

I apologize if this question has been asked before; I couldn't find it in a site search.

I have this sentence about teaching children safety rules:

The rules are different when you are together with your adults or when you are on your own.

My question is about the use of *or*. Is the sentence correct as it is, or does a different preposition need to be used? *and*? *from*? *than*?

My inclination is to use *than* because the rules are being compared.

Comment: See *[Which is correct: “__ is different from __” or “__ is different than __”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516)* and *[“Differ to”, “differ with” or “differ from”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1046)* for some helpful answers.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know if _from_ was still used if it did not immediately follow _different_.

Answer (score -1):

Correct is: "...different...from..."

Comment: It would be most helpful if you could cite your reference for this.